# Добавить поиск в Yandex Mapkit (Android, Java)

Tags: java, android, yandexmapkit

Нужно сделать поиск по адресу в Yandex Mapkit (Android, Java). Вывод информации по адресу как в яндекс картах не нужен, нужно просто по введённому пользователем адресу переместить камеру так, чтобы найденный объект был в центре экрана. В документации нет никаких примеров, по другим источникам тоже найти не могу.

Comment: А использование поискового слоя вам не подходит? https://yandex.ru/dev/maps/mapkit/doc/android-ref/full/com/yandex/mapkit/search/search_layer/package-summary.html/ О нём правда кратко в статье на хабре сказано, но похоже, что может подойти. https://habr.com/ru/company/yandex/blog/428564/

Answer (score 0):

Упрощенно как-то так, например. Ставим камеру на координаты первого найденого объекта:

```
@Override
public void onSearchResponse(Response response) {
    for (GeoObjectCollection.Item searchResult : response.getCollection().getChildren()) {
        Point resultLocation = searchResult.getObj().getGeometry().get(0).getPoint();
        if (resultLocation != null) {
            CameraPosition cameraPosition = new CameraPosition(resultLocation, 14.0f, 0.0f, 0.0f);
            mapView.getMap().move(cameraPosition);
            return;
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: камера на нужный объект становится, но начинает бесконечно срабатывать слушатель изменения позиции камеры и получается бесконечное обновление результатов поиска